# clarification of one-one proof?

Tags: real-analysis

clarification of proof of this statement:

> Let $\mathbb R[x]$ denote the vector space of all real polynomials. Let $D : \mathbb R[x] \rightarrow \mathbb R[x]$denote the map $Df = \frac{df}{dx}$, for all $f$. 
>   Then D is not one-one

My prove; i take $f_1 = 1 +x$ and $f_2 = 2+ x$,then $Df_1 =1$ and $Df_2 =1$. therefore $Df_1 = Df_2$ but $f_1 ≠ f_2 $, so $D$ is not one-one,,,

Is my proof is correct or Not ? Is my proof is proper proof for this statement or not? pliz verified and tell me the solution,,,i would be more thankful

Comment: Yes, it is entirely valid. When proving that a statement is false, all you have to do is provide a counter-example.

Comment: im not getting Counter example,,@Matrefeytontias  can u help me?

Comment: Well the $f1$ and $f2$ polynomials that you gave are a counter-example. The statement is that $D$ is not one-one. In order to prove this statement, you just need a counter-example, that is, show a particular setting that illustrates how $D$ is not one-one. For $D$ to be one-one would mean that $\forall f_1, f_2 \in \mathbb{R}[x], f_1 \neq f_2 \Rightarrow D(f_1) \neq D(f_2)$. Your $f_1$ and $f_2$ provide a counter-example because they verify the left side of the property, but not the right side.

Comment: @ Matrefeytontias Can u elaborate right side property.....actually  im not getting  what is left and right side property,??,,

Comment: In my previous comment, the line with the $\Rightarrow$ is the translation in mathematical terms of the property "$D$ is one-one". For it to be true, whatever is on the right of this arrow must be true when whatever is on the left is true. The idea of the counter-example is to show a setting that verifies the left side, but not the right side, thus implying that the property is false.

Comment: thanks i got it  @ Matrefeytontias,,,,one last doubt...Can  i say this is an onto ?  From my view as  according  to my function this is not onto  ,,,am i right ?

Comment: It is actually an onto : for any polynomial $f$, you can find a polynomial $F$ so that $D(F) = f$, using simple integration.

Comment: @ Matrefeytontias ....But if take $f = x+1$  $here $ D $=$1, that ie codomain≠range ,,,how it can be onto ?

Comment: The codomain isn't defined by a single input. It is the set of all attained outputs of the function. It is beyond the scope of this thread, but you can easily prove that every polynomial is the derivative of another polynomial, thus effectively proving that the codomain is in fact the whole of $\mathbb{R}[X]$.

Comment: thanks a lots @Matrefeytontias  and thanks for giving valuable time